# Thumbnail url clarification needs

Tags: magento2, product-images

I get the thumbnail url using the following code

```
$image_url = $this->imagehelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')->setImageFile($product->getFile())->getUrl();
echo $image_url;
```

It returns

http://localhost/magento/pub/media/catalog/product/**cache/e97e30f46ad3af2c4402aa864120074b**/w/b/wb02-green-0.jpg

My doubt is they mention the directory name **cache** in url. is this url is fixed one ? . I mean if erase the cache or run some command to remove cache files this url is exists or not . if not means how do i take the url

Comment: if you delete the cache you will be given a new URL

Comment: @PhilippSander i need the constant url . how i get that url . I dont want the temp url

Comment: @PhilippSander while i use "$product->getThumbnail(); " . It returns "/w/b/wb02-green-0.jpg" . I need the full url how do i get that